# predict conditional mean after truncated negative binomial regression

Tags: stata

I was using `tnbreg` command and wanted to predict conditional mean. As suggested by Stata for post-estimation after `tnbreg` code, I used `predict condmen, cm` to calculate the conditional mean, `E(y|y > ll)`. When  I manually calculated the conditional mean it was different than the output from Stata. So, I want to make sure that why the value I calculated is different than the Stata output. Could anyone please recommend me any supporting document describing the actual formula behind `predict, cm`?, then, I should be able to know that I am using the same formula manually as Stata does by its code.

Comment: (1) It is Stata, not STATA. It isn't an abbreviation, and there is no need to yell. (2) Show your code: provide a reproducible example. (3) Migrate the question to CrossValidated (although this is up to moderators): there is zero content in it that relates to deal with open data sources per se.

Answer (score 0):

The formula is given on p. 2388 of http://www.stata.com/manuals13/r.pdf. Without a reproducible example from you, it is impossible to discuss this further. You may have a bug, or they may have a bug -- looking at their formula, it seems like they've assumed that `ll=0`, as the formula quoted seems to assume the truncation point of zero.